# .htaccess rewrite to work with and without $_GET variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `player.php` page, and if no `playerid` GET variable is defined then it will get the current user's as defined in a global variable. This is working. It's just when I try to implement rewrites I'm having problems.

First I had this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^player/([^/]+) player.php?playerid=$1 [NC,L]
```

^ Worked fine if the `playerid` variable was set, but if not I just got 404

Next up I tried to fix that

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^player player.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^player/([^/]+) player.php?playerid=$1 [NC,L]
```

^ So instead now they all just load up the current user's profile regardless of the `playerid`

So I changed approach completely

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^player/([^/]+) player.php?playerid=$1 [NC,L]
```

^ This worked for not setting a `playerid`, but if one it set it appends .php on the end. So it thinks that `player/1` is `player/1.php`. Which of course breaks the queries I'm attempting to run to get the player info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is right but you need to disable `MultiViews` option.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^player/([^/]+)/?$ player.php?playerid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: I hate to say this but it worked 12 hours ago but it's not working now

Comment: Difficult to understand what might have happened in 12 hours on your server. This is indeed a tested & working solution for me.

Comment: I've managed to get it working again with `RewriteRule ^player/?(.*)$ player.php?playerid=$1 [NC,QSA]` not sure what was going on earlier but thank you for your help you certainly set me on the right track